# So if a problem is more difficult the language it represents is smaller?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, decision-problem

I'm reading the definition of polynomial time reducible:

> Let $L_1, L_2$ be two language. If $L_1$ is polynomial time reducible to $L_2$ then exists $f:\{0,1\}^*$ s.t. $\forall x\in\{0,1\}^*$ $$x\in L_1\iff f(x)\in L_2$$

For me this means the $L_1$ may be bigger (in cardinality) than $L_2$, but $L_2$ is more difficult since $L_1$ can be solved after reduced to $L_2$?

Comment: How would define the cardinality of an infinite set being larger than another infinite set (both being countable sets)?

Comment: You can find examples in which $L_1$ is a strict subset of $L_2$ (and vice versa).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$L_1$ and $L_2$ are always countably infinite, and thus "equally big".

If any language is finite, then it is "constant time" recognizable.

Comment: I forgot this fact that they're both infinite... Thanks!